# Trying to calculate the Pixastic color adjust values from a hex or RGB color

Tags: javascript, pixastic

I've inherited a small web application that has a feature where the user can select a color from a dropdown, then a portion of an image is colorized.

The colorization happens via a Javascript library called [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com).

Pixastic loads an image into a canvas element, the processes the image using its [Pixastic coloradjust](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/coloradjust/) function.

In my case, the image being processed is a transparent PNG with black/gray outlines. The end result is that only the black/gray outlines get colorized.

But here's the tricky part.

The Pixastic `coloradjust` function doesn't just take a hex or RGB color. It takes a set of *adjustment parementers* which adjust the red, green, and blue channels. Each adjustment value can be a decimal number from -1 to 1.

The `coloradjust` function basically works like this:

- Let `r` be the red channel adjustment value.
- Multiple `r` * 255 and let the result be `redVal`
- Loop over each pixel in the image
- Add `redVal` to the red value of the pixel (redPixel)
- If `redVal + redPixel` < 0, then set the pixel to 0
- If `redVal + redPixel` > 255, then set the pixel to 255
- Otherwise, set the pixel to `redVal + redPixel`
  *Do the same thing for the green and blue channels.

If it helps, here's the actual code of the [`coloradjust` function](https://code.google.com/p/chironjs/source/browse/trunk/src/nihilogic.dk/pixastic/coloradjust.js?r=405).

I have a list of existing colors and adjustment values.

My task is to add some new colors to the app but I'm completely stuck on figuring out how to calculate the color adjustment values for PIxastic given a hex color.

There doesn't seem to be any correlation between the existing hex colors and adjustment values so I'm afraid the existing adjustment values were someone figured out manually.

Here are a few example colors from the existing system:

- #603314

  - Red color adjust `-0.1`
  - Green color adjust `-0.5`
  - Blue color adjust `-0.3`
- #82bad4

  - Red color adjust `0.2`
  - Green color adjust `0.4`
  - Blue color adjust `0.4`

Given all of the above, how can I figure out the color adjustment values for a new hex color like `#cc9e3c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a shot at creating some functions to return red, green and blue scale, the way the problem is described. However, none of my calculations match the examples, so I am guessing that I do not understand the question fully. Nonetheless...

```
function redScale(colorInput) {return parseInt(colorInput.substring(1,3),16)/255 * 2 - 1;}
function grnScale(colorInput) {return parseInt(colorInput.substring(3,5),16)/255 * 2 - 1;}
function bluScale(colorInput) {return parseInt(colorInput.substring(5,7),16)/255 * 2 - 1;}
```

The substring method grabs the two digit hex value from the colorInput string. After I have the two-digit hex string, I convert it to decimal using parseInt. Divide it by 255, to get it to a scale from 0 to 1. Since the scale goes from -1 to 1 (a length of 2), you multiply it by 2 (to get a scale of 0 to 2), and then subtract 1, yielding a scale of -1 to 1. */

```
var colorInput = "#603314";

rCS = redScale(colorInput);
gCS = grnScale(colorInput);
bCS = bluScale(colorInput);
document.write("input: " + colorInput + "<br/>red: "+rCS+"<br/>","green: " + gCS + "<br/>" + "blue: " + bCS + "<br/><br/>");

colorInput = "#82bad4";

rCS = redScale(colorInput);
gCS = grnScale(colorInput);
bCS = bluScale(colorInput);
document.write("input: " + colorInput + "<br/>red: "+rCS+"<br/>","green: " + gCS + "<br/>" + "blue: " + bCS + "<br/><br/>");

colorInput = "cc9e3c";
rCS = redScale(colorInput);
gCS = grnScale(colorInput);
bCS = bluScale(colorInput);

document.write("input: " + colorInput + "<br/>red: "+rCS+"<br/>","green: " + gCS + "<br/>" + "blue: " + bCS);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll do some tests with what you've got there and see if that helps.

It's entirely possible that those hex colors I have don't directly correlate to the adjustment values and the adjustment values were found manually.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle of your code just as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/antelopelovefan/D3ubv/

Comment: Testing your scale functions with http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/coloradjust/ actually seems pretty close! Obviously, the adjustment #s aren't the same as the original ones, but the actual color overlays seem just about right.

Comment: It may be that the adjustment values will have to be manually derived. The function I created is a straight calculation which may not work well for colorizing from greyscale to the desired "tinted" color. Your results will also vary depending upon the distribution of the grey scales (the histogram) of the original images...

Comment: One last comment that lends itself to the fact that the adjustment values are "manually" created. They are only 1 significant digit (.2, not .2489078134) for example. I'd be willing to bet that they were manually derived.

Comment: I'm thinking you're correct. But your formula above seems close enough for my purposes. Thanks!